# Conditional transition not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I want to transition the green circle and then the red circle.  Transitioning the green circle works but when I transition the red circle, the green one reverts back to its original position.  How can I avoid this?

https://jsfiddle.net/jtr13/cwckLv29/1/

```
<svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="green">
    </circle>
    <circle cx="100" cy="150" r="20" fill="red">
    </circle>
  </svg>
<script>
    d3.selectAll("circle")
        .transition().duration(1000)
        .attr("cx", function() {
        if (d3.select(this)
            .style('fill') === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {  // green circle gets new cx
            return 150;
        } else {
            return d3.select(this).attr("cx")  // red circle keeps cx
        } } );

    d3.selectAll("circle")
        .transition().duration(1000).delay(1000)
        .attr("cx", function() {
        if (d3.select(this)
            .style('fill') === "rgb(255, 0, 0)") { // red circle gets new cx
            return 200;
        } else {
            return d3.select(this).attr("cx")  // green circle reverts to 
                                  // original cx, not changed cx... why???
        } } );

  </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an important but subtle distinction between attr and attrTween in a transition. The reason why you are having this problem stems from this distinction, while there may be easier ways of resolving this problem without worrying about the mechanics of it, my answer will look at the why of your problem and provides a solution in relation to that.

First, with some modification to your transitions, we can see the problem more clearly:

```js
 var svg = d3.select("svg");
 

 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .transition().duration(1000)
   .on("start",function() { console.log("start transition1"); })
   .attr("cx",150);

 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .transition()
   .delay(1000)
   .on("start",function() { return console.log("start transition2"); })
   .attr("cx", function() { 
       console.log("transition2 cx value: ", d3.select(this).attr("cx")); 
       return d3.select(this).attr("cx") 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="green">
    </circle>
</svg>
```

The value used for the end point of the transition 2 is determined prior to  transition 2 starting, in fact it is determined prior to transition 1 starting! As the value used in transition.attr() is determined prior to the transition start, at transition initialization, the value isn't updated after the first transition. This is also true if using .transition().transition() (as it not functionally different than the approach you have used).

From the life of a transition documentation for d3:

> Methods that specify target values (such as transition.attr) are
>   evaluated synchronously; however, methods that require the starting
>   value for interpolation, such as transition.attrTween and
>   transition.styleTween, must be deferred until the transition starts. ([link](https://github.com/d3/d3-transition#the-life-of-a-transition)).

Consequently, one solution is to use `attrTween`. This will allow for the cx value being calculated on transition start, rather than initialization (I've used a fill on transition for the following snippets to show the second transition is working, as cx is not modified):

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
 

 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .transition().duration(1000)
   .on("start",function() { console.log("start transition1"); })
   .attr("cx",150)
   
   
 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .transition()
   .delay(1000)
   .duration(1000)
   .on("start",function() { return console.log("start transition2"); })
   .attr("fill","steelblue")
   .attrTween("cx", function() { 
       var x = d3.select(this).attr("cx");
       console.log("transition2 cx value: ", x);
       return function() { return  x };
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="green">
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Based on the console, you can see a value for cx that is current as of the beginning of the transition.

Alternatively, you could opt not to initialize a transition until you get to the end of the previous one. Using the end event of the transition, we can create a new transition that is initialized with the current value of cx:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
 

 d3.selectAll("circle")
   .transition().duration(1000)
   .on("start",function() { console.log("start transition1"); })
   .attr("cx",150) 
   .on("end", function() {
     d3.select(this).transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .on("start",function() { return     console.log("start transition2"); })
       .attr("fill","steelblue")
       .attr("cx", function() { 
         var x = d3.select(this).attr("cx");
         console.log("transition2 cx value: ", x);
         return x;
      });
   
   
   })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="300" height="300">
    <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="green">
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Appreciate the detailed explanation. If I'm understanding correctly the delay doesn't change the fundamental fact that transitions are evaluated simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, the transition timer initializes right away regardless of delay, so both transitions' timers will be running at the same time.

Comment: @AndrewReid just as a curiosity, check my answer.

Comment: Agreed, the use of bound data (or classes or other identifier and/or attribute) will avoid the problem. While personally I found that sort of answer less satisfying as it didn't explain the root of the problem, that doesn't  negate the validity of other solutions, and I quite like your use of the transition to set the bound datum.

Comment: Using bound data is indeed a *wrong* solution, as I tried to make clear in the answer: OP should just use `.on("end"`, as everyone does. However, I like to show that something is possible, just for curiosity...

Comment: Wrong can be interesting and reveals behavior that might otherwise not be understood or known, and I am partial to curiosity. The question was also interesting. I had never closely looked at this aspect of a transition and didn't expect the expected behavior. Other than some frustration by making the mistake of testing with .attrTween to get realtime values, this was one of the more satisfying questions I've had a chance to answer, it definitely piqued my curiosity.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is not the idiomatic D3 and it will fail for the reasons already explained by [Andrew in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48308364/5768908). Just do what everybody does: `.on("end", etc...`.

However, just for the sake of curiosity and completeness, what you're trying to do is (almost) possible! Just bind data in the "first" transition and use the bound datum:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this)
      .style('fill') === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
      return d.x = 150;
    } else {
      return d.x = d3.select(this).attr("cx")
    }
  });

d3.selectAll("circle")
  .transition().duration(1000).delay(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this)
      .style('fill') === "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
      return 200;
    } else {
      return d.x
    }
  });
```

Here is the demo:

```js
d3.selectAll("circle").each(function() {
  d3.select(this).datum({
    x: 0
  })
});

d3.selectAll("circle")
  .transition().duration(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this)
      .style('fill') === "rgb(0, 128, 0)") {
      return d.x = 150;
    } else {
      return d.x = d3.select(this).attr("cx")
    }
  });

d3.selectAll("circle")
  .transition().duration(1000).delay(1000)
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    if (d3.select(this)
      .style('fill') === "rgb(255, 0, 0)") {
      return 200;
    } else {
      return d.x
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <circle cx="50" cy="100" r="20" fill="green">
  </circle>
  <circle cx="100" cy="150" r="20" fill="red">
  </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: I like that, very elegant.  But I will follow your advice and use `on("end",...` rather than try to forge my own path.